# Mysql replace not all string?

Tags: mysql

I have `column(pro_doc)` string like `[1,2,11,]`

```
UPDATE product SET prod_doc = REPLACE(prod_doc, '1,' , '') WHERE prod_id = 2
```

The result is `2,1`

I want become `2,11`,

I just want replace first `1`, not all `1`,

Have any solution?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123477/sql-search-replace-but-only-the-first-time-a-value-appears-in-record

Comment: It would be a lot easier to normalise your data and store each of the numbers in a separate record.

Comment: Does your string contain the `[` and `]`  or not? Either your input is correct or your output. And I assume you dont mean "first 1", but "complete integer value", right? So `[21,31]` will not become `[2,31]` if you replace the `1,`?

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)</kbd>.
Find the total occurence of `,` and use negative of that as the last argument of the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.

```
UPDATE product
SET prod_doc = 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   prod_doc, ',', -(
     ROUND(
       (
         LENGTH(prod_doc) - LENGTH(REPLACE(prod_doc, ',', ''))
      ) / LENGTH(','))
   )
)
WHERE prod_id = 2;
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dd80/1)</kbd>