# how to sort table which has varchar column having integer value with special characters

Tags: mysql, sql

how to sort table which has varchar column having integer value with special characters
i have a table in database which has a column of varchar type and values are like
Here i tried with below mysql query

```
   SELECT * FROM table order by CONVERT(seq_no,signed integer) ASC
```

Here i am getting result like this.

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    6_1
    6_2
    6_1_1
    6_1_2
    7
    8
    8_1
    8_2
    8_1_1
    8_1_2
    8_2_1
    8_2_2
```

But result should be like below.

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    6_1
    6_1_1
    6_1_2
    6_2
    7
    8
    8_1
    8_1_1
    8_1_2
    8_2
    8_2_1
    8_2_2
```

i tried with this query also but not getting exact result.

```
   SELECT * FROM table order by CONVERT(seq_no,signed integer) ASC,seq_no
```

Comment: Why not to just order by seqno?

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri I tried with sqno also, If i have more than 10  rows - using order by seqno result will be like this 1, 10, 11, 12,  2, 3, 4 , 5  , 6  , 6_1  ,   6_1_1  ,  6_1_2 ,6_2 , 7  ,  8    8_1  ,  8_1_1    8_1_2 ,8_2,   8_2_1,   8_2_2,9.  But result should 1,  2, 3, 4 , 5  , 6  , 6_1  ,   6_1_1  ,  6_1_2 ,6_2 , 7  ,  8    8_1  ,  8_1_1    8_1_2 ,8_2,   8_2_1,   8_2_2, 9, 10, 11, 12

Comment: Yes in this case regular ordering will not work. Don't you think that including this test data instead of the data you already provided is better?

Comment: here is test data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf1647/1

Comment: You don't have data like 6_1_10 do you?

Comment: @shree.pat18 .. Yes data will come like this also 6_1_10 and data will be like this also 6_1_10_1, 6_1_10_2. This is the menu and sub menu concept. like one menu will have N number of sub menus as well as one sub menu will have N number of Sub sub Menus like this

Comment: Syntax error! (at `id='18 order by...`)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
select * 
from table
where id = 18
order by cast(replace(INSERT(colname, LOCATE('_', colname), CHAR_LENGTH('_'), '.'),'_','') as decimal(10,4))
```

How this works:

- First, replace only the first underscore with a period/dot
- Next, remove all other underscores from the value.
- Finally, cast the number as a decimal and then order by the decimal value

e.g. '6_1_1' would first become '6.1_1' and then '6.11'. After casting to a number, this will be more than 6.1 i.e. '6_1' before transformation, lesser than 6.12 ('6_1_2) and also lesser than 10.

Note: Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123477/sql-search-replace-but-only-the-first-time-a-value-appears-in-record) for the replace first occurrence bit!

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17bdc7/11)

Comment: I was afraid that would happen. Is there any way you could change your data structure to reflect this hiearchy? Can't see that there's any reasonable way to deal with 6_1_2_10!

Comment: @shree.pat18 here is new table can you please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fde56/1

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert these lines into lines with fixed length parts.
For example let's convert it into parts with 10 letters length parts:

```
6_1_2 ->           000000000600000000010000000002
6123_1111_33333 -> 000000612300000011110000033333
1123_5555       -> 000000112300000055550000000000
```

In this case you can order by this string. You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [LPAD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) functions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
ORDER BY

CONCAT
(
LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX( concat(seq_no,'_') , '_', 1 ),10,'0')
,
LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( concat(seq_no,'_') , '_', 2 ),'_',-1),10,'0') 
,
LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( concat(seq_no,'_') , '_', 3 ),'_',-1),10,'0') 
,
LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( concat(seq_no,'_') , '_', 4 ),'_',-1),10,'0') 
)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c8fad/14)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:-

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT BatchNumber, CAST(CONCAT('<A>',REPLACE(BatchNumber,'_','</A><A>'),'</A>') AS XML) Xmlcol 
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rnk 
 FROM ApplicationBatchNumbers
)
,CTE1 AS
(
SELECT BatchNumber, SplittedString , rnk , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RNK ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) finalrnk 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM CTE) s
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT ProjectData.D.value('.', 'smallint') as SplittedString
        FROM s.xmlcol.nodes('A') as ProjectData(D)
    ) a
)
SELECT BatchNumber FROM CTE1
PIVOT ( MAX(SplittedString) FOR finalrnk IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) pvt
```

Comment: its not sql server