# MYSQL replace part of string with condition of char is numeric

Tags: mysql

Need help with this, as I am stumped with how to set the query update.

I will like to replace occurrences of `10x` to `20x` where `x` must be a numeric number. Also the numeric number can occur in any position. And the first two numeric digit of the numeric occurrence must be a `10`

eg: `tableA` - at field `colA` has the followings:

```
TOK101s
102YUZ
TAIP103v
ECC10
ECC10a
SCC_103
TD-102b
ZA1104z
```

Result after the query update should be:

```
TOK201s
202YUZ
TAIP203v
ECC10
ECC10a
SCC_203
TD-202b
ZA1104z
```

`ECC10` and `ECC10a` should not be updated since the 3rd char after `10` is not a numeric value.

`ZA1104z` should not be updated bec the numeric string 1104 does not begin with `10`.

Comment: this is a job for regular expressions. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a regexp-replace function built in, but you can search for a UDF that does it.

Comment: can I do a normal replace(colA,'10','20') but filter by table with a regular expression? is this do-able? Eg: update tableA set colA=replace(colA,'10','20') where colA REGEXP 'something'?

Comment: You can filter using `WHERE colA REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])10[0-9]'` to match 3 digits that begin with `10`. But what if the string looks like `ECC101ABC10`? This will replace both `10` substrings.

Comment: I see your point and the limitation. thank you very much for the fast response. Maybe there is a way to replace only the first occurrence? I can deal with that limitation. The system will likely never have ECC101A102 bec it is a template for class name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar and Misaka for:
[SQL: search/replace but only the first time a value appears in record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123477/sql-search-replace-but-only-the-first-time-a-value-appears-in-record)

```
update tableA set colA = IF(INSTR(colA, '10') <> 0, CONCAT(LEFT(colA, INSTR(colA, '10') - 1), '20', SUBSTRING(colA FROM INSTR(colA, '10') + CHAR_LENGTH('10'))), colA) where colA REGEXP  '(^|[^0-9])10[0-9]'
```

The above helped me to get what I wanted.