# Search, Replace in WordPress Posts Database. (Replace the first word in a post) SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, search, replace

Search, Replace in WordPress Posts Database.

```
UPDATE xxx_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'old_text', 'new_text')
```

What if you only want to change a word's initial appearance in a WordPress post?
Like, replace the first word in a post that has five words. Then apply that to all of the table's posts, ignoring all other terms that match except the first word in all posts.
[image]

Comment: which database system  are you using

Comment: Wordpress mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: search/replace but only the first time a value appears in record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123477/sql-search-replace-but-only-the-first-time-a-value-appears-in-record)

Comment: Well, This did not work: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(post_content, INSTR(post_content, 'VirtualBox')), 'VirtualBox', '[VirtualBox](https://example.com/category/softwares/virtualization/oracle-virtualbox/)'), SUBSTRING(post_content, INSTR(post_content, 'VirtualBox') + 1));`

Comment: maybe you should have test it before dismi9ssing it https://dbfiddle.uk/mOt04ot1

Comment: Ofcourse I tested. That's why I said its not working on my side. Let me share the screenshot, for some reason its not working on xampp. Am changing 17 posts saved in draft.  [https://prnt.sc/RwIxn04kaVAp](https://prnt.sc/RwIxn04kaVAp)

Comment: And it is clear that the table has 15 posts with that word. the select query is here   [https://prnt.sc/lKsXXlpAxtuA](https://prnt.sc/lKsXXlpAxtuA)

Comment: can you add the posts to the posts to the fiddle, so that i can see what is nit working

Comment: Am using xampp localhost. and the posts are saved as drafts, maybe you run xampp from your side.

Comment: run all queries in my link, the select and then the update on a copied table, xampp has nothing to do with it, the replacement needs exact patterns, so i provided a string where it works, and you need a post where ut doesn't, but the select you can run as oftenas you need

Comment: Its working, but as you can see their is (x) at the end of the link [VirtualBox](https://example.com/category/softwares/virtualization/oracle-virtualbox/)x

Comment: no sorry i can see nothing, ,ake a fiddle that shows your problem,

Comment: All links have x at the end. here is the screenshot  [https://prnt.sc/6h6czVTJRWRt](https://prnt.sc/6h6czVTJRWRt)

Comment: Also I was expecting to see " 16 rows affected. (Query took 0.0077 seconds.) " But I saw " 143 rows affected. (Query took 0.0077 seconds.) "

Comment: It seems that it doesn't change 16 posts in the draft as I had anticipated, The select query for the total items changed is here  [https://prnt.sc/M-MWUrCJiSW0](https://prnt.sc/M-MWUrCJiSW0)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mysql 8 use `regexp_replace` :

```
UPDATE xxx_posts SET post_content = regexp_replace(post_content,'old_text','new_text',1,1);
```

Comment: I think that's for the oracle database. I have looked for it online since it did not work.

Comment: It is working on mysql 8, Which mysql version are you using ?